# Add Ellipse Position within Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have an ellipse that I'd like to programatically put into a canvas. Unfortunately, the ellipse only draws in the top right. Any help?

```
SolidColorBrush newColor = HotSquare(col);
        Color newCol = getCol(col);
        Color newCol2 = getCol2(col);

        Ellipse el1 = new Ellipse();
        el1.Height = 40;
        el1.Width = 40;
        RadialGradientBrush rgb = new RadialGradientBrush();
        GradientStop gsa = new GradientStop();
        el1.StrokeThickness = 3;
        el1.Stroke = newColor;
        el1.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 6, 6 };
        gsa.Color = newCol;
        gsa.Offset = 0;
        rgb.GradientStops.Add(gsa);
        GradientStop gsb = new GradientStop();
        gsb.Color = newCol2;
        gsb.Offset = 1;
        rgb.GradientStops.Add(gsb);
        el1.Fill = rgb;

        Ellipse el2 = new Ellipse();
        el2.Height = 40;
        el2.Width = 40;
        el2.StrokeThickness = 3;
        el2.Stroke = newColor;

        //el2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Children.Add(el1);
        //canvas.Children.Add(el2);
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "\n   " + amnt.ToString();
        txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        txt.Height = 60;
        txt.Width = 60;
        txt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        //txt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        txt.FontSize = 12;
        canvas.Children.Add(txt);
        Border border = new Border();
        border.BorderBrush = newColor;
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
        border.Child = canvas;
        LocationRect lr = new LocationRect(North, West, South, East);
        HotspotLayer.AddChild(ele, lr);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't describing this in Xaml?

Comment: Because I'm adding them programatically, no direct manipulation of XAML as such (only at runtime).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call [Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) and [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) on the child element to set its position in the Canvas.

```
Canvas.SetTop(el2, 100);
Canvas.SetLeft(el2, 100);
```